# Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $[G ∶ H] \geq 2,$ then $p$ divides $[G ∶ H].$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $p$ be a positive prime number. Suppose $|G| = p^n$ for some positive integer $n.$

Assume the premise that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $[G ∶ H] \geq 2.$ Ok now I'm stuck haha. Using Lagrange's theorem since it is finite, can I then say this implies $\frac{|G|}{|H|} \geq 2$? Since $[G:H]= \frac{|G|}{|H|}$. I don't know if this is the right direction or helpful.

Comment: $|H|$ is a factor of $|G|$. What are the factors of $p^n$?

Comment: A subgroup of a $p$-group is also a $p$-group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[G:H]\ge 2 \implies H $is a proper subgrpup of$ G$

Since $H $is a proper subgroup of $G$

From Lagrange's theorem we can say the possible  orders of $H$ is one of $p^m  ,\text { where }m\in \{1,2,3,.., n-1\}$

$$[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$$
$$\implies [G:H]|H|=|G|=p^n$$
$$\implies [G:H] p^m=p^n$$
$$\implies [G:H]=p^{n-m} $$

Thus $p$ divides $[G:H]$

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange's theorem shows that
$$
[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}.
$$
Now the important thing is that this shows $[G:H]$ divides the order of $G.$ That is,
$$
[G:H]||G|=p^n.
$$

But since $p$ is prime, the only divisors of $p^n$ are $1$ and powers of $p$. And since we  are given that $|G|\neq 1$, we can conclude that $[G:H]$ is a power of $p,$ from which it follows that $p$ divides $[G:H].$

Answer (score 1):

$[G:H]=|G|/|H|\implies[G:H]||G|=p^n\implies [G:H]=p^k,\,0\lt k\lt n$.